# Java create array of instance

Tags: java

I have problem with my code here

```
Seller[] seller = new Seller[numberOfSellers];           // Declared global

// Some operations here

seller[i].setJoinDate(joinDate);
seller[i].setNumberOfPost(numberOfPost);
seller[i].setCustomerReview(customerReviewCount);
seller[i].setSafeTag(safeTag);
```

Then I have this Seller class with these methods

```
public void setJoinDate( String joinDate ) { this.joinDate = joinDate; }

public void setNumberOfPost( int numberOfPost ) { this.numberOfPost = numberOfPost; }

public void setCustomerReview( int customerReview ) { this.customerReview = customerReview; }

public void setSafeTag( String safeTag ) { this.safeTag = safeTag; }
```

Above is the shortened code of mine. If it is unclear please do point me where.

Basically I creating an array of instance. Then I will set the data.

Assuming the `joinDate`,`numberOfPost`,`customerReviewCount`,`safeTag` and lastly the `numberOfSellers` has no problem with is which it is.

The problem I had is at the setting of the data to the instance. Which is the `setJoinDate`,`setNumberOfPost`,`setCustomerReview`,`setSafeTag`. Anyone can help me detect my error here?

When I execute the program, it gives me this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at fyp.draft.pkg1.Design.actionPerformed(Design.java:247)
```

Comment: What is at `Design.java:247`

Comment: Where does numberOfSellers get initialised?

Comment: Its the line where `seller[i].setJoinDate(joinDate);` located

Comment: @PakkuDon it is before the `Seller[] seller = new Seller[numberOfSellers];`

Comment: Just show us your initialization of `numberOfSellers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

numberOfSellers doesn't seem to be set or equals zero at the time you run the code.
example:

```
  public static int b;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double[] d = new Double[b];

    d[5].doubleValue();
  }
```

leads to

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Comment: My problem is solved. My problem is that I declared the `Seller[] seller = new Seller[numberOfSellers];` at wrong place. I'm truly sorry for asking such a dumb question and wasting you guys time. But still your solution helps to provide me some hints in finding the error.

Answer (score 1):

Because of index equals `0` from provided exception, it seems that your variable `numberOfSellers` also equals `0`. That means, that your array `seller`  is always empty.

**BTW** There is no term `global` in Java. May be you mean that your array is static field of Class or just object variable (field)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your number `numberOfSellers` is initialised to `0` as the error says.

You can try the following piece of code;

```
int numberOfSellers = 3;
Seller[] seller = new Seller[numberOfSellers];           // Declared global

for(int i = 0 ; i<seller.length ; i++){
seller[i] = new Seller();
seller[i].setJoinDate(joinDate);
seller[i].setNumberOfPost(numberOfPost);
seller[i].setCustomerReview(customerReviewCount);
seller[i].setSafeTag(safeTag);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to initiallize the array:

```
 for(int i=0;i<numberOfSellers;i++)
 { 
    seller[i] = new seller();
 }
```

Comment: I did as you said and still get an error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`